# Surface Traces Ellipses and Hyperbolas

Tags: calculus

For the surface defined by $z^2 =x^3+2xy^2-x$, describe the traces in planes parallel to the yz-plane. Consider traces in planes $x=k$. For what values of k the traces are ellipses? And for what values of k the traces are hyperbolas that open in the z-direction?

**What I have done so far, but I doubt that this is correct:**

A plane parallel to the yz-plane has the equation:  $ x \,=\,k$ (constant).

In the equation let $ x = k\!:\;\;z^2\:=\:k^3 + 2ky^2 - k$

So we have:   $z^2\:=\:2ky^2 + k^3 - k$

$2k$ is a constant; call it  $a$.
$k^3 - k$ is a constant; call it  $b$.

The equation has the form: .  $z^2\:=\:ay^2 + b\quad\Rightarrow\quad z^2 - ay^2 \:=\:b$

The traces are hyperbolas.

If  $b$ is positive, the hyperbola is "vertical":  $\begin{array}{cc}\cup \\ \cap\end{array}$

If  $b$ is negative, the hyperbola is "horizontal":  $\supset\;\subset$

If  $b = 0$, we have a pair of intersecting lines:  $z \:=\:\pm\sqrt{a}\,y$